# Pirush on Tamid

Tags: sources-mekorot, authorship, maseches-tamid, kodshim

[Ezra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11486/ezra) and I have been learning the gemara of Tamid over the phone. In the standard edition (Vilna and subsequent) there is one main pirush (presumably the same one as in the other minor Kodashim gemarot). While the marginalia (gilyonot, R' Gershom, Geonim, hagahot) are all sourced on the daf, the main pirush is not.

Who is the main pirush on Tamid attributed to ?

Is this the same source as the pirush on the other minor masechtot in Kodashim ?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15520/759

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101401

Answer (score 8):

There’s dissenting opinions who the anonymous commentator is (AKA, “ha’mefaresh”):

Some attribute it to R. Yitzchok b. Baruch, a student of Rabbenu Tam. [E. E. Urbach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_Urbach) disproved this attribution; R. Yitzchok appears to have compiled a work on Tamid (quoted, for example, by Raabad on the page) but the one on the page isn’t it.

Others attribute(d) it to Rashbam, while some early authorities believed it to be from Rashi although this has been demonstrated not to be the case. See [this](https://daf-yomi.com/Data/UploadedFiles/DY_Item/16369-sFile.pdf) article (Kovetz al Yad, N.S. vol. 15, p. 107) for precise sources.

On the topic of Tamid, may I recommend [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/42956617.pdf) very worthwhile read.

(P.S. Greatest part of the question is what seems to be an East-coast-West-coast *[havruta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chavrusa)*[ship], I imagine facilitated by MY.SE.)

Comment: Indeed, we started conversing because of MY. :)

Answer (score 3):

In the introduction to the sefer "Pirush HaRishonim Al Meseches Tamid" he quotes the Chok Nosan who writes that it is the **Ri Bar Baruch** one of the Balei Tosfos. He also quotes the Yavetz who writes that it is **Rabbeinu Shmaya** a student of Rashi. He questions both of these theories.

Comment: For the actual published work of R. Shmaya on Tamid, see the link in my answer.